# Jersey multipart file upload is not working in grails-rs

Tags: grails, jersey, mule, jax-rs, multipart

I am getting `400`, `Bad Request`, while uploading file through Jersey Multipart from code base in Grails 2.5.1 `jaxrs:0.11` plugin.

Code in REST:

```html
    @POST
    @Path("/uploadTemplate")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        println("Upload Template Called................................................"+uploadedInputStream)

    }
```

Calling from Client:

```html
final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    
final Client client = Client.create(config);

final WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8090/ExportService/fa/templateManager/template").path("uploadTemplate");

println("URL............................" + resource.getURI());

final File fileToUpload = new File("/home/nsubedi/TestOneSheet.xlsx");

final FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", fileToUpload, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

if (fileToUpload != null) {
    multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);
}

final ClientResponse clientResp = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
println("Response: " + clientResp.getStatus() + " Info..........." + clientResp.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
```

I did lots of google, found somewhere in stackoverflow about changing in `mule` but don't know how.
Please some one help me here. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like there is issue with 'jax-rs' plugin, since new version in Grails supports Web service implicitly with URL Mapping, created it and called with HttpClient ... If anyone is stuck here then I can help with that...